# Tengo duda en la sintaxis en el código para colocar hatch a una figura con VBA EXcel - AutoCAD

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un código en VBA Excel para colocar Hatch en una figura de AutoCAD, Ya intenté todo y no funciona. No sé si la sintaxis está mal escrita o si tengo problemas con las librerías. Saludos, Anexo código.

```
pto = AutoCAD.Application.ActiveDocument.Utility.GetPoint(, "indique el punto")

X = pto(0): Y = pto(1)

Z(9)=3

Z(10)=25

Z(8)=1.25

Dim Rad As Double, pc(0 To 2) As Double

Dim RefFT(0 To 0) As AcadEntity

Dim SolidVar As AcadHatch

Rad = Z(8) / 2

num = 0

For i = 1 To Z(9)

Set SolidVar = Aut0CAD.Application.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace.AddHatch(1, "SOLID", True)

pc(0) = X + 5 + num: pc(1) = Y + 2

Set RefFT(0) = AutoCAD.Application.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace.AddCircle(pc, Rad)

SolidVar.AppendOuterLoop (RefFT)

SolidVar.Evaluate

SolidVar.Layer = "Var"

num = num + Z(10)

Next i
```

Comment: *Ya intenté todo y no funciona.* Esa descripción no sirve de nada. ¿Da error el código? ¿Has probado a debugearlo ejecutándolo step by step con F8?